# Find dimension of subspace of $M_{2,3}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find **dimension** of the subspace of $M_{2,3}$ of all matrices $A$ for which $A\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\3\end{pmatrix}=0$.

I know that $A$ should be $2\times 3$ and the resulting matrix $2\times 1$, so I got

$$\begin{pmatrix}a & b & c \\ x & y & z  \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 2 \\3\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a+2b+3c \\ x+2y+3z \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$

but I have no idea how to go further.

Can someone help me?

By the way, if I am asked to find the dimension, is it sufficient to provide a basis and count the number of elements or should I also show that the elements in the basis are linearly independent and form all the matrices in the given subspace (even if it is as trivial as hell?) :)

Comment: Basis is enough. Then by definition the basis vectors are linearly independent. So nothing trivial as hell necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completing your work you have:
$$
\begin{cases}
a=-2b-3c\\
x=-2y-3z
\end{cases}
$$
So the matrix $A$ has four free parameters and the dimension  of the subspace of these matrices is $4$.

Comment: Could you also help giving the basis of this subspace?

Answer (score 1):

View $M_{2,3}$ as the space of vectors $(a,b,c,x,y,z)$. Clearly this linear space has dimension $6$. A canonical basis would be $e_1=(1,0,0,0,0,0), \ldots ,e_6=(0,0,0,0,0,1)$. Since we have two linear equations, which enable us to express two basis vectors by the other four, we have dimension $6-2=4$ for the space in question.